# Valriable might not have been initialized?

Tags: java, variables, initialization

I'm trying to convert the "bonusStr" variable into a double, so it can be used in the calculation. However when trying to compile I get the error "variable bonusStr might not have been initialized". I know that this is a really newbie question, but any help given will be appreciated.

Many thanks!

Wasn't expecting so many responses in a few minutes - I've resolved the issue. Thank you to all. :-)

```
import static javax.swing.JOptionPane.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

class Question3 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String intrestRateStr = showInputDialog("What is the interest rate?");    
        int intrestRate = Integer.parseInt(intrestRateStr);

    String depositStr = showInputDialog("How much will you deposit?"); 
        double depositAmount = Double.parseDouble(depositStr);

   DecimalFormat pounds = new DecimalFormat("£###,##0.00");

   double amountInterest = calcAmount(intrestRate, depositAmount); 

   String bonusStr;
          double bonus = Double.parseDouble(bonusStr);

   if (amountInterest >= 5000.00)
       bonus = (+100.00);
   else if (amountInterest >= 1000.00)
       bonus = (+50.00);


   double finalAmountInterestBonus = bonus + amountInterest;

    showMessageDialog(null, 
            "Your savings will become " + pounds.format(finalAmountInterestBonus));
}

private static double calcAmount(int intRate, double depAmount) {
    double result = depAmount*(1.0 + intRate/100.0);
    return result;
 }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String bonusStr;
double bonus = Double.parseDouble(bonusStr);
```

As the error states `bonusStr` is not initialized (you did not affect a value to it), so you should not use it inside `Double.parseDouble` until it has a value.

Answer (score 1):

```
   String bonusStr;
          double bonus = Double.parseDouble(bonusStr);
```

You never set a value to `bonusStr` - by default it is going to be `null`. You are using it before giving it a value. Try :

```
String bonusStr = "0";
```

It's a good idea to give it a default value, say 0 or something can help you diagnose that you have forgotten to give a proper value.

Answer (score 0):

Your program will raise a NumberFormatException. You do a parseDouble of a string that has no value. You have to set the bonusStr with a value before doing a parseDouble on it.